# Static Website on Google Cloud Fails to Connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have used the how-to document to create a simple website on Google Cloud using a bucket, load balancer, etc. I can access the website using the googleapis.com URL, but I cannot access the site using the domain name. I am not yet using a certificate so this is plain http://africanshade.org. If anyone can help, I would very much appreciate it. I am new to this method of webhosting.

When I attempt to access the site with http://africanshade.org, the error is ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. If I use https://storage.googleapis.com/africanshade/home.html I can see everything fine.

Comment: How long did you wait after setting up the configuration? It takes a few minutes or longer for DNS changes to refresh (TTL) and the load balancer front ends to initialize.

Comment: Not very long. However other browsers were picking up the site at the new location fairly quickly, so I think it was just my own PC confused by the number of times I had attempted to get this working. All seems good now. Thanks very much for this response!

Answer (score 0):

This problem had two contributing factors. First, the DNS change had to propagate which took a little bit of time. Second, the browser on my PC had likely cached bad information as I has used it a number of times in my attempts to test if the site was available.

All is good with this issue now and consider this question answered.

Comment: If you misconfigure DNS and receive a negative response, that response is cached for the time period in the SOA TTL. Basically, that means configure DNS correctly the first time otherwise you will have caching conflicts on your machine and on the Internet DNS servers that serve your Internet connection. The default SOA TTL is 3600 seconds. That means making a DNS change and waiting for the TTL to expire in between tests. Each DNS resource record also has a TTL to wait for expiration.

Comment: Same applies when correcting bad DNS information, which was the case here. Thanks for the response!